# Doing is_writeable with phpseclib

Tags: php, phpseclib

I'm using phpseclib for SFTP connection and need a request like PHP `is_readable` and `is_writeable`. phpseclib supports only the methode `fileperms`. What is the best way to get this functions?

Answer (score 0):

I think this pull request adds the features you're looking for:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/pull/981

It adds `is_readable`, `is_writable` and `is_writeable`.

edit: this is now in the 1.0.2 release:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/releases/tag/1.0.2